# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'

Tags: python

Someone could help me, please? I was running some python scripts and I found the following warning:

````
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/yohelcruz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'

Remainder of file ignored```
````

Comment: No, no one in the world can help you if you say just *I was running some Python scripts*.

Comment: In case it helps I face the same issue when I run "conda create" with miniconda.

Answer (score 38):

I ended up creating an issue on conda: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11931

After some additional digging, I found that running

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

solved the issue

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Just a heads up for others though you must run it from outside your existing conda env if you have one. ```conda deactivate``` should do the trick.